# Are politically engaged Americans less likely to identify as independents?

Tags: united-states, parties

I feel like politically engaged Americans are less likely to identify as independent. This is because parties actually sort of stand for something in a way that they didn't so much 30 years ago.

Is that true?

Comment: I have never been affiliated with a party and I have voted in every election.  I do not attend caucus meetings, put signs in my yard or campaign for anyone or anything, but I study issues and candidates carefully.  So I am less politically engaged in some ways, but I always vote after careful consideration.  I have a number of acquaintances who follow a similar pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [study](https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2019/05/15/facts-about-us-political-independents/) about this question. In particular it says:

> Independents – particularly the 7% of Americans who don’t lean toward a party – are less politically engaged than partisans. In a survey conducted shortly after the November 2018 midterm election, just a third of those who don’t lean toward either party (33%) reported voting. Democratic leaners (48%) and Republican leaners (54%) were considerably more likely to say they voted, though both groups reported lower rates of voting than partisans.